# Dask pct_change

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I am new to Dask. I have a pandas df with a sorted DateTimeIndex of size appox. 30M rows. I am trying to do this pandas op in dask (bc the grouping is costly in pandas)

```
df0['close_pct_change'] = df0.groupby('tic').close.pct_change(periods=1).dropna()
```

In other words, group the data by `tic` then find sequential (periods=1) price changes, which is monotonically increasing in time (since the index is a sorted DateTimeIndex). My dask code is:

```
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client,progress
import dask.dataframe as dd

client = Client(n_workers=4, threads_per_worker=2, memory_limit='8GB')

df = dd.from_pandas(df0, npartitions=10)
df = df.persist()

df.groupby('tic', dropna=True).close.pct_change(1)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'pct_change'
```

which i dont understand. I thought `pct_change` is a series function.

I am aware that a `df.groupby(columns_no_index).apply(user_fn)` requires shuffle, but `df.groupby(columns_with_index).apply(user_fn))` is much faster. Therefore this aggregation works

```
dask_job = df0 \
    .set_index('tic')\
    .pipe(dd.from_pandas, npartitions=20)\
    .groupby(['tic']) \
    .apply(lambda x: x.close.pct_change(1))
```

However, the above returns a multiindex with `tic` as both level1 and level2 indicies, whereas we care about the DateTimeIndex being the second index (e.g. level1=tic, level2=DatetimeIndex, level3=precent_change.)

As mentioned in the comment below, if i try to write my own `pct_change` as in

```
df.groupby('tic',dropna=True).close.transform(lambda x: x.diff(1)/x, meta=('close_pct_change', 'f8'))
```

I get the following error:

`ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 183100 elements, new values have 183921 elements`

not clear to me why

Comment: i want to use dask bc the dataset is approx. 30M rows. and yes, the partitions are separable in `tic`. I'll look into `delayed`. thank you for the suggestiion

Comment: its a single .gz file but multiple files would be actually more convenient. but the files will be date based, not tic based. that is, each file would have all `tics` for a certain date range

Comment: I see. The reason I was asking is that when `dask.dataframe` does `groupby`, it will have to shuffle the data, and this is expensive.

Comment: understood.. if i make the tic the index (as in the `dask_job` code above) the groupby seems to work but is lacking the date index and the result is a multiindex with both level1 and 2 as `tic`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228338/discussion-between-sultanorazbayev-and-peyman).

Answer (score 2):

I found this to work

```
df = dd.from_pandas(df0, npartitions=200)
df = df.persist()

df = df.groupby('tic').apply(lambda x: x.assign(close_pct_change=(x.close.diff(1)/x.close)*100))
df  = df.compute().droplevel('tic')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, this is only an indirect solution, but it should work:

1. split the large `.gz` file into a set of files based on the `tic`.
2. with `tic`-based files, you can now have a function that loads a file and runs pandas on it.
3. wrap the function in delayed.

Rough example:

```py
from dask import delayed
@delayed
def process_file(path_to_file):
    df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file) # parquet is probably better, but that's not important
    df['close_pct_change'] = df.groupby('tic').close.pct_change(periods=1).dropna()
    return df

results = dask.compute([process_file(f) for f in file_list])
```

Comment: Although I can see the solution I am concerned the ETL to get the data into tic level files is not clean. the data is timeseries so if splitting gz file is an option then splitting it into dates would be much more cleaner since we can write each day data to disc and run the dask job

Comment: if i try to write my own `pct_change` as in 

`df.groupby('tic',dropna=True).close.transform(lambda x: x.diff(1)/x, meta=('close_pct_change', 'f8'))` I get the following error: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 183100 elements, new values have 183921 elements`
not clear to me why